# Salesforce Manage Package Org API Usage Limit

Tags: apex, visualforce, managed-package, appexchange

I'm thinking about doing including some HTML parsing/screen scrapping html to get the Org current API Limit Usage/Max API limit, though there is report to say the total limit in last 7 days it didn't help with total org limit and coming with calculating of user * API limit, may or may not be accurate and lot of code possibly.

Option 1
write a HTML parsing with Jquery of Company page to get MAX API Limit and current API usage LIMIT

Option2

DOM Parsing server side of Salesforce Company Page?

which option is better and also from the perspective of security review?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a pilot program for querying this data via the REST API. See the REST API docs, and contact support if you're interested.

Comment: https://instance.salesforce.com/services/data/v29.0/limits/

 if i use this api then the each customer need to file the case to get the api enabled before installing our package, which is cumbersome?

Comment: Yes, currently orgs have to request it. It should be GA in 3-6 months (based on historical pilot to GA release cycles). It provides the total limit/current threshold for the org.

Comment: I consider this as valid solution moving forward and also implementing option2 for backup